# Error when compiling python 3.3.2

Tags: python, compiling

I downloaded Python 3.3.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 and I followed the instructions of README to compile the files:

```
./configure
make
test make
sudo make install
```

but when I applying the command MAKE I hold the following error:

```
**FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists (mode 775 !=  expected mode 755): 'build/lib.linux-i686-3.3'
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Error 1**
```

The 'build/lib.linux-i686-3.3' is a directory but I can't figure out to what file is refered that FileExistsError

Comment: Why do you need Python 3.3.2?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have probably the package with python3.3.1 installed. Unfortunately, the file `lib.linux-i686-3.3` has the same major version. Either remove python3.3.1 (which will break oh so many dependencies), or install python in another directory, for example using

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local
```

Comment: I checked with the locate command and there is only one single file with that name, placed in the folder of Python 3.3.2

Comment: Can you do `dpkg -l | grep python3.3`, please?

Comment: I sorted chmodding build/lib.linux-i686-3.3         chmod 755 build/lib.linux-i686-3.3

Comment: cool! answer the post yourself and accept your answer.